# I need to modify these hash functions so that it gives value in range 0<x<10^9

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, bloom-filter

I was trying to implement bloom filter in java but the problem is that the hash functions are returning values in range -10^20

```
public long APHash(String str)
{
    long hash = 0xAAAAAAAA;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if ((i & 1) == 0)
        {
            hash ^= ((hash << 7) ^ str.charAt(i) * (hash >> 3));
        }
        else
             {
            hash ^= (~((hash << 11) + str.charAt(i) ^ (hash >> 5)));
        }
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: I can't use sparse array because i am trying to implement bloom filter and i have to store 1 at this address of array 1453132441229891328
 and using sparse array won't solve the problem.  I want to do something like this  
a[1453132441229891328]=1;

Comment: `HashMap<BigInteger, Boolean>` would probably be suitable for this. In what form are you getting the values in 10^20 range?

Comment: I cant use array list since i need to store 1 at position 1453132441229891328 directly i wont be storing any other value in array at that time when I will be storing 1 at position 1453132441229891328
The first line in my program after declaring array list will be 
a[1453132441229891328]=1;

Comment: Do you know how much is 10^20? Even `long` cannot store such large values. A simple array that size far exceeds a 64-bit address space and need 67 bits computer or more. No computer architecture ever has that large space, most have only 48-52 bits and still be safe for maybe centuries ahead as you can almost never have that much memory.

Comment: I didn't mean you should completely replace your question, just add to it, or post a new, separate question. Now the responses don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java Map or Set or similar data structures is missing the whole point of Bloom filters! E.g. a Java HashSet/HashMap entry is at least 20 bytes in a 32-bit JVM and 40 in a 64-bit one. The whole point of a Bloom filter is memory efficiency: one bit can represent more than one set element. So for a table that's 50% populated, you'd be trading away a factor of 160 (for the 64-bit table, only 80 for 32-bits) in memory efficiency! Bad idea.

You should fix your hash functions.  This is just a matter of choosing a prime number N for the Bloom bitmap size and computing the hash values mod N.

If this is the signature of your current hash function:

```
long APHash(String s) { ... }
```

Then just use

```
long getHashInRange(String s) { 
  return APHash(s) % PRIME_BITSET_SIZE;
}
```

If PRIME_BITSET_SIZE will fit in an `int`, then return `int` instead.  An `int` index will allow for a table size (PRIME_BITSET_SIZE) of 2 billion.

The prime-ness of the modulus makes pathological collision conditions less likely.  This [table of primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/) is a good resource for picking sizes.

Don't use an array of `byte` (or anything larger) to store 1 or 0 in each element. Again, you'd be giving up a factor of 8 in memory use.  For table sizes of 2^31-1 bits or less, use instead [a `BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) or other appropriate container that stores each bit in a bit. If the table is at all large, be sure to create the `BitSet` with initial size `PRIME_BITSET_SIZE` rather than letting it grow dynamically. For larger tables - which require `long` indices - use the [the Apache OpenBitSet](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/OpenBitSet.html) class or similar.

Comment: public long APHash(String str)
   {
      long hash = 0xAAAAAAAA;

      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
      {
         if ((i & 1) == 0)
         {
            hash ^= ((hash << 7) ^ str.charAt(i) * (hash >> 3));
         }
         else
         {
            hash ^= (~((hash << 11) + str.charAt(i) ^ (hash >> 5)));
         }
      }

      return hash;
   }
  This is my hash function what can be possible edit so that it doesn't gives a value larger than this

Comment: @tobey put code into backticks `like this` or no one will read your unreadable code

Comment: `public long APHash(String str) { 
        long hash = 0xAAAAAAAA; 
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
                   if ((i & 1) == 0) { 
                               hash ^= ((hash << 7) ^ str.charAt(i) * (hash >> 3));
                    } 
                  else { 
                               hash ^= (~((hash << 11) + str.charAt(i) ^ (hash >>5)));                           } } return hash; }` This is my hash function what can be possible edit so that it gives a value in range 0<x<10^9

Comment: @tobey Keep in mind that the number of values matters. If your hash will be an `int`, then a `HashMap` with the parameters above (in 64-bit JVM) will take up *less* memory than a `BitSet` unless you store more than cca 3.5 million values into it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Cinnam's comment, you do not want an Array because that is way to much memory and as you pointed out, you hit the limit.  A Map, where the key is the value of the output of the bloom function, would be ideal.  The Map would only grow to fulfill the amount of entries in it, and not to fill the number of possible entries by the 10^20 bloom output that using an Array would cause.

The final question is what to use as the key.  You can use String, long, or BigInteger.  The value of the Map will be a Boolean.

EDIT:  To fulfill th O(1) requirement, then a HashMap is preferred over a TreeMap, but it really does not matter if you only have one entry in it.

Comment: I cant use array list since i need to store 1 at position 1453132441229891328 directly i wont be storing any other value in array at that time when I will be storing 1 at position 1453132441229891328 The first line in my program after declaring array list will be a[1453132441229891328]=1;

Comment: Do NOT use an array.  Use a Map.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html  My answer does not say to use an Array.  It is saying to use a Map,

Comment: Just to add - `Long` is not big enough for a key, its max value is roughly 10^19. `String` and `BigInteger` would be fine.

Comment: @Cinnam Thanks for clearing that up.  I took a look at the MAX long number and the number in the OP's comment.  Max long 9223372036854775807 > 1453132441229891328 in comment.  But I still agree, you may encounter a number too big for long when playing in that region of the number line.

Comment: It turns out that OP's hash function results are actually `long`, so you were right. It wasn't mentioned in the question so I just assumed the worst.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes usually have a much bigger range than the array you want to use them in. That's ok, just reduce their range.

Common ways to reduce the range are discarding the upper bits (but depending on the hash function, this may be bad), XORing the upper bits with the lower bits (a bit safer, but can still easily lead to clustering), or reducing the hash code modulo a prime number (safest but slower). They may be preceded by some "mixing" operations, this is especially important if you're going to discard the upper bits. Java's HashMap uses mixing+discarding, C#'s Dictionary uses modulo a prime (they're not Bloom Filters of course but the same considerations apply to their hashing schemes).

You do not need to use the hash codes "as is", giving an incredibly huge bloom filter (or a sparse one, which is really not the point of a Bloom Filter). The optimal size of the bloom filter can be calculated from the expected number of items you will put into it, the number of hash functions, and the desired false positive rate. It does not depend on the range of the output of the "raw" hash function, you just map that to the desired range in a way that gives a good distribution.